# Android png images big in memory

Tags: android, image, png

I have an application in android that has an `imageflipper`. Problem is, after about 8 images loaded to memory, I get an out of memory error.

Well, I tried to do dynamic image loading, so that if the user flips 2 images, I'll load next 2 to memory and delete 2 first ones. It kind of works, but it is ugly and I have trouble when user flips images back(`imageflipper.showprevious()`).

I can't really shift all images and place new images to the beginning.

My question is:
Is there a better way to do this kind of stuff? Resizing images didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code snippet to over the memory related issues, We can over come this problem by the help of `isRecycled()` method. Add this code with yours, here `finalImage` is my `BitmapDrawable` and `R.id.image_viewer` is my imageview, you can change it yours

```
 @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {

             finalImage.setCallback(null);
             if (!((BitmapDrawable) finalImage).getBitmap().isRecycled()) {
             ((BitmapDrawable) finalImage).getBitmap().recycle();
             }
             finalImage = null;
            unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.image_viewer));
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            // scaledBitmap.recycle();
            System.gc();
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
            if (view.getBackground() != null) {
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
                ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inSampleSize = 2;
//this will decrease bitmap size,
// but also affect quality of the image, 
//so just play with this value to spot the good one;
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, opts);
```